# returns single value while using for loop in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to return 2 tables data in one request using for loop. When I print the result its showing correctly but while return first table result only showing. I have tried with yield its not working for Response. I have used return both inside and outside of the loop but not achived. Request please give your suggestion.

```
table_name = "table1,table2"

table_multiple = list(table_name.split(","))
con = psycopg2.connect(user=username, host=host, database=db_name, password=password)
for tablenames in table_multiple:
    t_data = pd.read_sql_query(f"select * from {tablenames}", con)
    table_json = t_data.to_json(orient="records")
    tableDatum = json.loads(table_json)
    print(tableDatum)
    return Response('tableDatum' : tableDatum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop stops after the return statement, it doesn't do the second execution because a return statement kills the loop and the function running it. If the return is in your main then your script stops here.

You should put your extracted data in an array to append these data to the array then return the array afterward.

```
table_name = "table1,table2"

table_multiple = list(table_name.split(","))
con = psycopg2.connect(user=username, host=host, database=db_name, password=password)
tableDump = []
for tablenames in table_multiple:
    t_data = pd.read_sql_query(f"select * from {tablenames}", con)
    table_json = t_data.to_json(orient="records")
    tableDatum = json.loads(table_json)
    print(tableDatum)
    tableDump.append(tableDatum)
return Response('tableDump' : tableDump)
```